# How can I cast an std::vector<const unsigned char> to a const std::vector<unsigned char>?

Tags: c++, casting

How can I cast an `std::vector<const unsigned char>` to a `const std::vector<unsigned char>`, without copying the data?

```
Parser::Parser( const std::vector< unsigned char > &i_Data )
{
    Parse(i_Data);
}

Parser::Parser( std::vector< const unsigned char > i_Data )
{
    Parse( (std::vector< unsigned char >)(i_Data) );  // <-- Error
}

int Parser::Parse( const std::vector< unsigned char > &i_Data )
{ ... }
```

This is the error message from Visual C++ 2010:

> Error C2440   'type cast' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to
>   'std::vector<_Ty>'

Comment: I assume you are trying to avoid copying the data.  Is that correct?

Comment: @NathanOliver: correct.

Comment: You should  take a break and think about why you want to do that..

Comment: @JesperJuhl: because I have that constructor already used extensively, and I need to generalize it so that it can deal with different data types.

Comment: `std::vector<const unsigned char>` is undefined behavior anyway.

Comment: Normally if you need to cast `const` away there is a design flaw.

Comment: @T.C. Why is that?

Comment: @NathanOliver In C++03, container elements are required to be `Assignable`; in C++11 and later, allocator requirements forbid `const` value types.

Comment: @T.C. Oh cool.  I did not know that was spelled out restriction.  Thanks.

Comment: @T.C., NathanOliver: I have to see if I can fix it, because the incorrect syntax is already used in other parts of the code by others. In the meantime, is there any way to force a cast of this kind?

Comment: No, not without invoking more undefined behavior. Barry's answer has the correct approach for something like this.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I cast an `std::vector<const unsigned char>` to a `const std::vector<unsigned char>`, without copying the data?

You can't. The two types are unrelated.

Instead of having such a strict interface (taking a `std::vector< unsigned char > const&`), you should generalize it to take a pair of iterators. In this case, perhaps just two pointers to `const unsigned char`:

```
Parser(unsigned char const* begin, unsigned char const* end)
{
    ...
}
```

Now if you want you can add the two `vector` constructors to delegate to this one via:

```
Parser(std::vector<unsigned char> const& v)
: Parser(v.data(), v.data + v.size())
{ }
```

Note: Pre-C++11, since `vector` doesn't have a `data()` function yet, the way to delegate a vector to two pointers be to write something like:

```
template <class T, class A>
T* data(std::vector<T, A>& v) {
    return v.empty() ? 0 : &v[0];
}

template <class T, class A>
T const* data(std::vector<T, A> const& v) {
    return v.empty() ? 0 : &v[0];
}
```

And then simply use `data(v)` instead.

Comment: Not sure if VS2010 has delegating constructors. But they are delegating to a member function anyway so it's not a big issue. Also, getting `end` as a pointer is slightly tricky.

Comment: @T.C. `data()` and `data() + size()`?

Comment: Yes. The "slightly tricky" part is that someone might try `&*end()`. `vector` doesn't have `data()` until C++11, and I don't know how much C++11 is in VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

With this cast it compiles correctly:

```
Parser::Parser( std::vector< const unsigned char > i_Data )
{
    Parse( (std::vector< unsigned char >)(i_Data) );             // <-- Error
    Parse( ( const std::vector< unsigned char > &)( i_Data ) );  // <-- OK
}

int Parser::Parse( const std::vector< unsigned char > &i_Data )
{ ... }
```